# Python is not printing my input in while loop

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with my python code as it is not printing anything after I input something into the compiler.

I'm trying to write code that uses a while loop and allows the user to enter an album's artist and title. Then I should be able to call `make_album` with the user's input and print the dictionary that's created.

However, after I enter the artist and title, nothing prints.

Here is my python code:

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title, num_tracks = ''):
    """Return artist and album title name."""
    CD1 = {'sonic': artist_name, 'his world': album_title}
    CD2 = {'shadow': artist_name, 'all hail shadow': album_title}
    CD3 = {'silver': artist_name, 'dream of an absolution': album_title}
    if num_tracks:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title + ' ' + num_tracks
    else:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title
    return CD.title()

while True:
    print("\nEnter album's artist and title: ")
    print("\nEnter 'q' at anytime to quit")

    a_name = input("Artist name: ")
    if a_name == 'q':
        break

    a_title = input("Album title: ")
    if a_title == 'q':
        break

make_album(a_name, a_title)
formatted_album = make_album(a_name, a_title)
print(formatted_album)
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what I may be doing wrong? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should those last 3 lines be indented in once?

Comment: Put the bottom 3 statements inside the loop

Comment: where does the title attribute come from for the CD? Are you getting an error (AttributeError perhaps)? If so, reproduce the error you are receiving here with full traceback (in the question itself, not in comments). I suspect you also need to indent the last statements to be inside the loop and several other issues also. You should step through this in a debugger as there are likely numerous issues.

Comment: It turns out the last 3 lines did have to be indented and placed in the while loop which was causing the compiler to not print out the user inputs. The book that I'm reading was using an example similar to this code where the bottom portion was cut-off and placed on the next page which made it hard to tell that it was supposed to be indented. ^^; Thank you everyone for your help though, this problem was driving me insane. @_@

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to print out the type of your "a_name" and see what it says.

My guess is that your usage of `input` does not yield what you expect.  Try `raw_input` instead.

The python course has the following to say on [`input`](http://www.python-course.eu/input.php):

> The input of the user will be interpreted. If the user e.g. puts in an
>   integer value, the input function returns this integer value. If the
>   user on the other hand inputs a list, the function will return a list.

That means that if you want a string, e.g. `'q'`, you have to enter, literally, `'q'`.

You may want your input to be takes as a string, no matter what you type, and leave interpretation up to your implementation. Then you better call `raw_input`.